# how to run cmd as administrator with psexec

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, administrator, psexec

i tried to open cmd as administrator manually
and run this command

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp" /v UserAuthentication /d 0x00000000 /f
```

and success
[cmd as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnL97.png)

but when i tried to open from psexec `PsExec.exe -u 106000088**\*** -p password CMD` and run same command the responses said access is denied

[from psexec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y5X5.png)

I am using same credential when run as administrator, and also the user is same when i run whoami . please help me to solve this